# Convert decimal number to BigInteger in Java

Tags: java, type-conversion, biginteger

I am trying to convert `10000000000000000000000000000000` to `BigInteger`. 
But it is not converting.
My code is

`BigInteger number = BigInteger.valueOf(10000000000000000000000000000000);`

It is showing `The literal 10000000000000000000000000000000 of type int is out of range`.

Is there any way to convert this number as I have to use this number as integer in my programme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole point of BigInteger is to support numbers `long` and `int` cannot so you can't use those.  What you can do is use a String.

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("10000000000000000000000000000000"):
```